# R plotting has issues with producing text/number labels

Tags: r, docker, conda

I am having issues with my general R plotting functions. From a fresh R restart, and without loading any packages, I run this:

```
png(file ="mtcars.png", width = 1600, height = 1600, units = "px", res = 300)

hist(mtcars$mpg, breaks = 'FD', col = 'blue', xlab = 'MPG', main = 'MPG of mtcars Dataset')

dev.off()
```

And the result is what you see in this post. There's some weird squares where the labels should be. I am running R in a new docker image and have no idea what I forgot to install. Somebody help!
[image: mtcars histogram]

My dockerfile contains:

```
RUN conda install -y r-base && conda install -c bioconda -y r-devtools
RUN \
/opt/conda/lib/R/bin/R -e "getOption(\"unzip\") ; options(repos = list(CRAN=\"http://cran.rstudio.com/\")) ; Sys.getenv(\"TAR\") ; options(unzip = \"/opt/conda/bin/unzip\") ; \
Sys.setenv(TAR = \"/bin/tar\"); library(devtools) ; install.packages(c('Seurat','XML','ggplot2')) ; \
devtools::install_github(repo = 'satijalab/seurat-wrappers',quiet=T) ; \
if (!requireNamespace(\"BiocManager\", quietly = TRUE)) { \
    install.packages(c(\"BiocManager\"), quiet = T) \
} ; \
BiocManager::install('monocle')  ; devtools::install_github('hms-dbmi/conos')"
```

Comment: I take that you're using docker for R. Can you show the Dockerfile?

Comment: added docker statements. I am starting from a miniconda base